Best way to resolve conflicts between application packages
I am developing a package that will be used by 3-party applications that I have no control over whatsoever.
I am wondering what is the best way to solve conflicts between packages.
For example:
Lets say a 3-party app wants to use my package called external-package.
├── Dockerfile
├── app.py
├── external-package
│   ├── Core
│   │   ├── ClassA.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
└── requirements.txt

App.py:
from Core import ClassA

app = ClassA()
app.send()

ClassA:
import backoff
import requests

class ClassA:

    @backoff.on_exception(
        backoff.expo,
        requests.exceptions.RequestException,
        max_tries=35,
        backoff_log_level=20,
        max_time=2400,
        raise_on_giveup=True,
    )
    def send(self):
        requests.get('https://google.com')

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    libtool \
    wget \
    --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./external-package /app/external-package
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir /app/external-package

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

Running this container will outputs an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    app.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/backoff/_sync.py", line 87, in retry
    wait = _init_wait_gen(wait_gen, wait_gen_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/backoff/_common.py", line 23, in _init_wait_gen
    return wait_gen(**kwargs)
TypeError: expo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'backoff_log_level'

Because, the external-package must have backoff ==1.9.2, and the 3-party must have backoff ==2.2.1 but the container has backoff ==1.9.2.
Keep in mind this is an example only for backoff and I want a way to solve this issue for any library there is.

What is the relationship between app.py and the external package? Does app.py import it, or is it called as an external process? Generally, the answer is "install things into seperate virtual environments" -- one for your app, and one for the external package -- but without knowing how these two things interact it's unclear if that would be an appropriate solution.

@larsks
This is just an example of a 3-party app trying to use my package called (external-package). Normally you would use pip install external-package or add it to requirements.txt file.
app.py is the 3-party app trying to import my package classA.

I have encountered this situation a few times while working with Python projects, and unfortunately, as of today there is no elegant way to install multiple versions of the same module in a the same Python environment.
What I'd do usually is to focus on what is within my control, which is the dependency of my own code (in your case, the external-package). Is it possible to not fix the backoff version for external-package (i.e. always default to latest version)? If yes, make the necessary code changes in external-package code to achieve that.
If not, then the next best alternative is probably to copy the source code of backoff==1.9.2 manually into external-package, which is a highly inelegant solution that may lead to issues in the future.

so basically, maybe creating a vendor approach for all packages in my  external-package? is this possible.. is there a tool that mange this?

and you said "highly inelegant", can you elaborate on that please?

As of today, I'm not aware any reliable vendor dependency tool for Python, so you have to do everything manually.

I consider this solution inelegant because you may need to continuously keep track of future releases of backoff in case there are important bug fixes, and even then, there is no guarantee that you may be able to implement those changes into your copy of the code (e.g. the fixes require python version not supported by your own package, etc.)
